# express multer how to upload different types of files with different sizes

Tags: node.js, express, multer

```
const express = require("express");
const multer  =  require("multer");
const makeDir = require('make-dir');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const upload = multer({
  storage: Storage,  
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log("upload fileFilter req ::", req.file); 
      checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
}).fields(
  [
    {
      name:'comppic',
      maxCount:1
    },
      {
      name:'userpic',
      maxCount:1
      },
      {
      name:'usercv',
      maxCount:1
      }      
  ]
);

function checkFileType(file, cb) {    
  console.log("file:::::::::::::::", file);
}
```

I am using above code to upload file. In that how do I check for size of file which is uploading and returns error if file size exceeds.

```
console.log("upload fileFilter req ::", req.file);  // output undefined
console.log("file:::::::::::::::", file);
```

output

```
file::::::::::::::: {
  fieldname: 'userpic',
  originalname: 'DSC01416.JPG',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg'
}
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different file size limitation based on file type, there is size of file in `req.rawHeaders` so I write a logic in `fileFilter` based on type file, It's work to me,multer  set `.any` for multer. `req.rawHeaders` is array, one of the item is size of file, in my request,size of file is in last item in Array so I used `req.rawHeaders.slice(-1)[0]`

in this logic, size of `.pdf < 1 Mb` and `.png,.jpeg,.jpg < 4 Mb`

```
const multer = require('multer');
const { v4: uuid } = require("uuid");

const TYPE_IMAGE = {
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
  'image/jpg': 'jpg'
};
const TYPE_File = {
  'application/pdf': 'pdf',
};

const fileUpload = 
  multer({
    limits: 500000, 
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/images');
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const ext = (TYPE_IMAGE[file.mimetype]) ? TYPE_IMAGE[file.mimetype] : TYPE_File[file.mimetype];
        cb(null, uuid() + '.' + ext);
      }
    }),
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      let size = +req.rawHeaders.slice(-1)[0]
      let isValid =false;
      if(!!TYPE_IMAGE[file.mimetype] && size < 4 * 1024 * 1024  ){
        isValid = true
      }
      if(!!TYPE_File[file.mimetype] && size < 1 * 1024 * 1024  ){
        isValid = true
      }
      let error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type!');
      cb(error, isValid);
    }
  }).any();


module.exports = fileUpload;
```

Comment: I have image and doc two file types with 200 kb and 1mb size limit respectively inthis case how does i write code. Your solution allows till 4 mb for any File type which is not expected. Any best solutions.

Comment: Yo can not aceess to size in multer, you can creat new instance of multer for file or check size in router

Comment: Can we use fs with multer to check file size inside multer filefilter property? Since i have used multer as middleware its necessary to check file size in multer file.

Comment: let size = +req.rawHeaders.slice(-1)[0] it returns connect.sid string still size isnt found.

Comment: can you console.log(req.rawHeaders) and show me the results

Comment: Got resolved by using req.rawHeaders[5] Thanks alot